# django forms - reusing form request functions

Tags: python, django

I have a base.html which most of my pages inherit.  Inside it defines a header which contains a search box.  The code for the search box is some thing along the lines of....

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'search_button' in request.POST:
        location = request.POST['location']

         # Do something with location here and redirect to another page...

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/lostandfound')
```

I have a couple of questions.  First of all, how do I ensure that this code is sat in all my other views without rewriting it every time, this wouldn't be very DRY!!

Also how do I redirect to another page and pass the variable 'location' along with it?  HttpResponseRedirect isn't the right way to do it i'm sure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should POST your search form to it's own search view, and display the results on that page.

Comment: does a view have to have an associated URL or can it just be a stand alone function def?  also I definitely want to pass the results to another view.

Comment: Yes.  Create a new url @ `/search/` (or similar) that points to your search view, and `POST` to that.